Как сбросить кэш(контекст) языковой модели saiga
С небольшой командой работаем над созданием умного телеграм бота, используем языковую модель IlyaGusev/saiga_mistral_7b_gguf. Исходя из получаемых ответов, складывается ощущение что модель обучилась на неправильных данных, мы хотим получать в скрипт бота json, а она присылает этот json напрямую в чат с человеком. Есть ли способ очистить кэш или контекст модели, которая развернута в LM Studio?
